# Magento 2 category export to CSV file

Tags: magento2, upgrade, csv, export

I would like to export created Magento 2 categories to CSV file and create upgrade script that imports csv file to Magento 2 just like sample data csv file.

Comment: For export, you can adapt this : https://gist.github.com/Nolwennig/a90670efe9bb113b525901c8e54a22a8

Comment: @kilis Have you get any solution of import export categories in csv ?

Comment: @kilis  I am also facing issue in export categories in csv. Could you please let me know if you have get any solution of export categories in csv? your help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That's in our backlog ( ticket: MAGETWO-4026 ).  Would be great if you could give us a PR for that functionality.

Comment: Sure. I need it for our project.

Comment: Hi @Chuck, any news on this? We would need this functionality as well.

Comment: @Chuck  I am also facing issue in export categories in csv. Could you please let me know if you have get any solution of export categories in csv? your help would be appreciated. Thanks